# Xuggler crashes JVM in 64 bit

Tags: java, xuggler

I am using xuggler for video converting. Following criteria are set in my system

```
window7
xuggler 5.4 version 
OS/Java 64 bit
```

When I run the program JVM crashed with following log

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ee76520, pid=43188, tid=43624
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [xuggle6677784747721795797.dll+0x736520]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
```

**But I tried it in OS/Java 32 bit, its working**

How can I acheive in 64 bit Java? Would you please share your an idea?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379910/exception-access-violation-thrown-when-reading-a-video-from-a-file-with-xuggle/67870750#67870750). I answered with my experience there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replicate this problem on different computers running Windows 64-bit? Xuggler 5.4 has been known to have compatibility issues with some very specific x64-processors.

If the problem is specific to Windows, you can also consider only releasing a 32-bit version. Computers running Windows 64-bit also support 32-bit JVM's.

Comment: Yea its replicating on different windows, but downgrading to 32 bit not better solution....hmmm thinking to switch xuggler to other API....do you know other api?